# JAVA, storing a .mpg video file frames into byte array

Tags: java

i got a code to convert frames buffered from a video file to byte array. i did some modification in the code by removing the part of converting to jpeg image( due to unavailability of sun library).
although the code is running for mpg video file but not for avi file. although it is reading from the file but it is storing only zeroes in the byte array:

```
printDataInfo(inBuffer);// it is printing the frame information
       byte[]x=(byte[])inBuffer.getData();// but it is storing all 0s
            System.out.println(x[2]);
```

problem with avi file:

```
***Failed to build a graph for the given custom options.
Failed to realize: com.sun.media.ProcessEngine@8ed465
  Cannot build a flow graph with the customized options:
    Unable to transcode format: IV50, 320x240, FrameRate=3.8, Length=0 0 extra bytes
      to: RGB, 24-bit, Masks=3:2:1, PixelStride=3, LineStride=-1
      outputting to: RAW
Error: Unable to realize com.sun.media.ProcessEngine@8ed465***
```

here is the full code:
package javaapplication1;

```
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.media.*;
import javax.media.control.*;
import javax.media.format.*;
import javax.media.protocol.*;
import java.awt.image.*;


// If you prefer to amend the sun example FrameAccess.java then to get every frame include
// out.setFlags(in.getFlags() | Buffer.FLAG_NO_SYNC); when copying the input attributes 
// in process(Buffer in, Buffer out). This avoids dropping frames whilst not removing likes
// of end of media events.

public class vid2jpg extends Frame implements ControllerListener
{
 Processor p;
 Object waitObj = new Object();
 boolean stateOK = true;
 DataSourceHandler handler;
 imgPanel currPanel;int imgWidth;int imgHeight;
 DirectColorModel dcm = new DirectColorModel(32, 0x00FF0000, 0x0000FF00, 0x000000FF);
 MemoryImageSource sourceImage;Image outputImage;
 String sep = System.getProperty("file.separator");
 //NativeEncoder e;
 int[] outvid;
 int startFr = 1;int endFr =13;int countFr = 0;
 boolean sunjava=true;

 /**
 * Static main method
 */
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
  if(args.length == 0)
  {
   System.out.println("No media address.");
   new vid2jpg("file:testcam04.avi"); // or alternative "vfw://0" if webcam
  }
  else
  {
   String path = args[0].trim();
   System.out.println(path);
   new vid2jpg(path);
  }
 }

 /**
 * Constructor
 */
 public vid2jpg(String path)
 {
  MediaLocator ml;String args = path;

  if((ml = new MediaLocator(args)) == null)
  {
   System.out.println("Cannot build media locator from: " + args);
  }

  if(!open(ml))
  {
   System.out.println("Failed to open media source");
  }
    }

 /**
 * Given a MediaLocator, create a processor and start
 */
 private boolean open(MediaLocator ml)
 {
  System.out.println("Create processor for: " + ml);

  try
  {
   p = Manager.createProcessor(ml);
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
   System.out.println("Failed to create a processor from the given media source: " + e);
   return false;
  }

  p.addControllerListener(this);

  // Put the Processor into configured state.
  p.configure();
  if(!waitForState(p.Configured))
  {
   System.out.println("Failed to configure the processor.");
   return false;
  }

  // Get the raw output from the Processor.
  p.setContentDescriptor(new ContentDescriptor(ContentDescriptor.RAW));

  TrackControl tc[] = p.getTrackControls();
  if(tc == null)
  {
   System.out.println("Failed to obtain track controls from the processor.");
   return false;
  }

  TrackControl videoTrack = null;
  for(int i = 0; i < tc.length; i++)
  {
   if(tc[i].getFormat() instanceof VideoFormat)
   {
    tc[i].setFormat(new RGBFormat(null, -1, Format.byteArray, -1.0F, 24, 3, 2, 1));
    videoTrack = tc[i];
   }
   else
   tc[i].setEnabled(false);
  }  
  if(videoTrack == null)
  {
   System.out.println("The input media does not contain a video track.");
   return false;
  }  
  System.out.println("Video format: " + videoTrack.getFormat());

  p.realize();
  if(!waitForState(p.Realized))
  {
   System.out.println("Failed to realize the processor.");
   return false;
  }

  // Get the output DataSource from the processor and set it to the DataSourceHandler.
  DataSource ods = p.getDataOutput();
  handler = new DataSourceHandler();
  try
  {
   handler.setSource(ods); // also determines image size
  }
  catch(IncompatibleSourceException e)
  {
   System.out.println("Cannot handle the output DataSource from the processor: " + ods);
   return false;
  }

  setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
  currPanel = new imgPanel(new Dimension(imgWidth,imgHeight));
  add(currPanel);
  pack();
  //setLocation(100,100);
  setVisible(true);

  handler.start();

  // Prefetch the processor.
  p.prefetch();

  if(!waitForState(p.Prefetched))
  {
   System.out.println("Failed to prefetch the processor.");
   return false;
  }

  // Start the processor
  //p.setStopTime(new Time(20.00));
  p.start();

  return true;
 }

 /**
 * Sets image size
 */
 private void imageProfile(VideoFormat vidFormat)
 {
  System.out.println("Push Format "+vidFormat);
  Dimension d = (vidFormat).getSize();
  System.out.println("Video frame size: "+ d.width+"x"+d.height);
  imgWidth=d.width;
  imgHeight=d.height;
 }

 /**
 * Called on each new frame buffer
 */
 private void useFrameData(Buffer inBuffer)
 {

  countFr++;
  if(countFr<startFr || countFr>endFr)return;

  try
  {
   printDataInfo(inBuffer);byte[]x=(byte[])inBuffer.getData();
System.out.println(x[2]);// at this point it is storing only 0s in the buffer
   if(inBuffer.getData()!=null) // vfw://0 can deliver nulls
   {
    if(outvid==null)outvid = new int[imgWidth*imgHeight];
    outdataBuffer(outvid,(byte[])inBuffer.getData());
    setImage(outvid);

   }
  }
  catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e);} 
 }

 /**
 * Tidy on finish
 */
 public void tidyClose()
 {
  handler.close();
  p.close();
  //if(e!=null)e.close();
  dispose(); // frame
  System.out.println("Sources closed");
 }

 /**
 * Draw image to AWT frame
 */
 private void setImage(int[] outpix)
 {
  if(sourceImage==null)sourceImage = new MemoryImageSource(imgWidth, imgHeight, dcm, outpix, 0, imgWidth);
  outputImage = createImage(sourceImage);
  currPanel.setImage(outputImage); 
 }

 /**
 * Block until the processor has transitioned to the given state
 */
 private boolean waitForState(int state)
 {
  synchronized(waitObj)
  {
   try
   {
    while(p.getState() < state && stateOK)
    waitObj.wait();
   }
   catch (Exception e)
   {
   }
  }
  return stateOK;
 }

 /**
 * Controller Listener.
 */
 public void controllerUpdate(ControllerEvent evt)
 {
  if(evt instanceof ConfigureCompleteEvent || evt instanceof RealizeCompleteEvent || evt instanceof PrefetchCompleteEvent)
  {
   synchronized(waitObj)
   {
    stateOK = true;
    waitObj.notifyAll();
   }
  }
  else
  if(evt instanceof ResourceUnavailableEvent)
  {
   synchronized(waitObj)
   {
    stateOK = false;
    waitObj.notifyAll();
   }
  }
  else
  if(evt instanceof EndOfMediaEvent || evt instanceof StopAtTimeEvent)
  {
   tidyClose();
  }
 }

 /**
 * Prints frame info
 */
private void printDataInfo(Buffer buffer)
    {
  System.out.println(" Time stamp: " + buffer.getTimeStamp());
  System.out.println(" Time: " + (buffer.getTimeStamp()/10000000)/100f+"secs");
  System.out.println(" Sequence #: " + buffer.getSequenceNumber());
  System.out.println(" Data length: " + buffer.getLength());
  System.out.println(" Key Frame: " + (buffer.getFlags()==Buffer.FLAG_KEY_FRAME)+" "+buffer.getFlags());
    }

 /**
 * Converts buffer data to pixel data for display
 */
 public void outdataBuffer(int[] outpix, byte[] inData) // could use JavaRGBConverter
 {
  boolean flip=false;
  {
   int srcPtr = 0;
   int dstPtr = 0;
   int dstInc = 0;
   if(flip)
   {
    dstPtr = imgWidth * (imgHeight - 1);
    dstInc = -2 * imgWidth;
   }

   for(int y = 0; y < imgHeight; y++)
   {
    for(int x = 0; x < imgWidth; x++)
    {
     byte red = inData[srcPtr + 2];
     byte green = inData[srcPtr + 1];
     byte blue = inData[srcPtr];
 //    System.out.println(red);
          //                                      System.out.println(green);
            //                                    System.out.println(blue);
     int pixel = (short)((red & 0xff) << 16 | (green & 0xff) << 8 | (blue & 0xff) << 0);
     outpix[dstPtr] = pixel;
                                       // System.out.println(pixel);
     srcPtr += 3;
     dstPtr += 1;
    }
    dstPtr += dstInc;
   }
  }
  Thread.yield();
 }


 /***************************************************
 * Inner classes
 ***************************************************/

 /**
 * A DataSourceHandler class to read from a DataSource and displays
 * information of each frame of data received.
 */
 class DataSourceHandler implements BufferTransferHandler
 {
  DataSource source;
  PullBufferStream pullStrms[] = null;
  PushBufferStream pushStrms[] = null;
  Buffer readBuffer;

  /**
  * Sets the media source this MediaHandler should use to obtain content.
  */
  private void setSource(DataSource source) throws IncompatibleSourceException
  {
   // Different types of DataSources need to handled differently.
   if(source instanceof PushBufferDataSource) 
   {
    pushStrms = ((PushBufferDataSource) source).getStreams();

    // Set the transfer handler to receive pushed data from the push DataSource.
    pushStrms[0].setTransferHandler(this);

    // Set image size
    imageProfile((VideoFormat)pushStrms[0].getFormat());
   }
   else
   if(source instanceof PullBufferDataSource)
   {
    System.out.println("PullBufferDataSource!");

    // This handler only handles push buffer datasource.
    throw new IncompatibleSourceException();
   }

   this.source = source;
   readBuffer = new Buffer();
  }

  /**
  * This will get called when there's data pushed from the PushBufferDataSource.
  */
  public void transferData(PushBufferStream stream)
  {
   try
   {
    stream.read(readBuffer);
   }
   catch(Exception e)
   {
    System.out.println(e);
    return;
   }
                          //  System.out.println(readBuffer.getData());
   // Just in case contents of data object changed by some other thread
   Buffer inBuffer = (Buffer)(readBuffer.clone());

   // Check for end of stream
   if(readBuffer.isEOM())
   {
    System.out.println("End of stream");
    return;
   }

   // Do useful stuff or wait
   useFrameData(inBuffer);
  }

  public void start()
  {
   try{source.start();}catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e);}
  }

  public void stop()
  {
   try{source.stop();}catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e);}
  } 

  public void close(){stop();}

  public Object[] getControls()
  {
   return new Object[0];
  }

  public Object getControl(String name)
  {
   return null;
  }
 }

 /**
 * Panel extension
 */
 class imgPanel extends Panel
 {
  Dimension size;
  public Image myimg = null;

  public imgPanel(Dimension size)
  {
   super();
   this.size = size;
  }

  public Dimension getPreferredSize()
  {
   return size;
  }

  public void update(Graphics g)
  {
   paint(g);
  }

  public void paint(Graphics g)
  {
   if (myimg != null)
   {
    g.drawImage(myimg, 0, 0, this);
   }
  }

  public void setImage(Image img)
  {
   if(img!=null)
   {
    this.myimg = img;
    update(getGraphics());
   }
  }
 }

}
```

i would be really grateful if someone can help with this.

Comment: Please look at your post and ask yourself: "Will anyone want to read this?" If the answer is no, then try to make it so that someone would want to read it. Hint: Formatting matters.

Answer (score 0):

It seems likely that whatever library you have doing your video decoding doesn't have AVI codecs.